# Clear data event for OTHER apps

Tags: android, google-play-services

I searched a lot and couldn't find, is it possible to listen to Clear Data event of application? But! not for my own application, then for Google Play Services app? Is it possible to register to some kind of event?

Comment: No. It is not possible. Such functionality is not provided in the Android API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can listen for package cleared broadcast of other applications by adding `android.intent.action.PACKAGE_DATA_CLEARED` action and `package` scheme to your BroadcastReceiver.

AndroidManifest.xml example:

```
<receiver
    android:name=".PackageDataClearedReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_DATA_CLEARED" />
        <data android:scheme="package" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

For getting data from the intent, use this in your BroadcastReceiver:

```java
String action = intent.getAction();
if (Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_DATA_CLEARED.equals(action)) {
    Integer uid = intent.getIntExtra(Intent.EXTRA_UID, Integer.MIN_VALUE);
    String packageName = context.getPackageManager().getNameForUid(uid);
}
```

or this:

```java
String action = intent.getAction();
Uri data = intent.getData();
if (Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_DATA_CLEARED.equals(action) && data != null) {
    String packageName = data.getSchemeSpecificPart();
}
```

As you already mentioned in your question, it's not possible to listen for package cleared broadcast of your own application.

Answer (score 1):

Try to listen for the broadcast intent

android.intent.action.PACKAGE_DATA_CLEARED

Answer (score 1):

I managed to find a solution, 7383 answer is not full, it's important to add `scheme="package"`

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_DATA_CLEARED" />
<android:scheme="package" />
```

And in your `BroadcastReceiver` you get package info in `intent.getData()`.

Comment: You got the further solution from my answer, you should upvote my answer as it is not wrong. My way of doing providing solutions is to give pointers to the right thing but not spoon feed the solution.